# Adding a Second Attribute to Basic Search (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hey everyone I have a basic search function here that allows me to search for users by name, I also want to add an email attribute but I'm not sure how. I think this should be a relatively easy fix. Heres all the relevant code:

Search form:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'search_field' %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
```

Controller:

```
@usersearch = User.search(params[:search])
```

User model:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking to do a search of names and then a search of Emails that match portions of the names, or are you looking to search emails if the search term looks like an Email address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add OR statement with email:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ?', "%#{search}%","%#{search}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```